# Generic method not working when used with the Integer wrapper class

Tags: java, generics

I have this following HeapSort method

```
public static <T extends Comparable<T>> void sort(List<T> in, List<T> out) {
    Heap<T> heap = new Heap<T>();
    Iterator<T> it = in.iterator();
    while (it.hasNext()) {
        heap.add(it.next());
    }

    while (!heap.isEmpty()) {
        out.insertLast(heap.remove());
    }
}
```

inside my `Heap<T extends Comparable<T>>` class. I am now attempting to use it to sort a list of Integers, but I get this error:

```
The method sort(List<T>, List<T>) in the type Heap<Integer> is not applicable for the arguments (List, List)
```

Here is the main method:

```
public class HeapSortTester {

    @SuppressWarnings({ "unchecked", "rawtypes" })
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Heap<Integer> heap = new Heap<>();
        List<Integer> unsortedList = new ArrayList();       
        List<Integer> sortedList = new ArrayList();     

        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
            int number = (int) (Math.random() * 1000) + 1;          
            unsortedList.add(number);
        }

        heap.sort(unsortedList, sortedList);    //ERROR GIVEN HERE

        System.out.println("Unsorted List: " + unsortedList + "\n");
        System.out.println("Sorted List: " + sortedList + "\n");
    }

}
```

Should `HeapSortTester` extend `Comparable<T>` or something along those lines? Or how else can I allow the sort method to be used with the `Integer` type, while keeping its definition generic?

Comment: `@SuppressWarnings({ "unchecked", "rawtypes" })`.......

Comment: Maybe don't use rawtypes. Ever?

Comment: I was unaware what rawtypes even were until now, but even without using them I still have the same error on the `Sort` method

Comment: what is the error you are getting? please post it in your question

Comment: You are suppressing warnings. Do not suppress warnings unless you _really_ know what you're doing. Remove this annotation and fix the warnings.

Comment: @Blip the error is in my question - `The method sort(List<T>, List<T>) in the type Heap<Integer> is not applicable for the arguments (List, List) `

Comment: Also, why are you calling a `static` method on an instance of `Heap`?

Comment: What kind of `List` are you using anyway? Standard `java.util.List` doesn't have a `insertLast()` method...

Comment: @MadhusudanaReddySunnapu doesn't matter, the method is `static`.

Comment: @BoristheSpider The heap class was provided to us as a template with blank `insert(T t)` and `remove()` methods which we had to implement as an assignment. The `static void sort()` method was already provided within this class. The second part of the assignment is to show this method sorting 1000 random numbers

Comment: Great, but that doesn't explain why you are calling a `static` method on an instance does it?

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
List<Integer> unsortedList = new ArrayList();       
List<Integer> sortedList = new ArrayList();
```

to

```
List<Integer> unsortedList = new ArrayList<>();       
List<Integer> sortedList = new ArrayList<>();
```

Note the diamond operator (`<>`) used to instantiate `ArrayList`.

Comment: I have tried that already and it gives the same error unfortunately